# Linear Algebra, Basis, Linear Span

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose S spans a vector space V.
Then:

(i) Any maximum number of linearly independent vectors in S form a basis of V.

(ii) Suppose one deletes from S every vector that is a linear combination of
preceding vectors in S. Then the remaining vectors form a basis of V

Isn't the second statement wrong? What if S={0,u1,u2,...,un), then the zero vector will always remain a part of S and hence, S can never be reduced to a basis?

Comment: $0$ is linear combination of the empty sequence.

Comment: Does this mean we take the preceding vector of the initial vector as the empty sequence?

Comment: Yes, if $0$ is allowed in the sequence then we must view it as a linear combination of the empty set and delete it immediately. Otherwise your concern is valid.

Comment: I see, thanks. That works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.